# Track origin of file deletion during make

Tags: linux, cmake, makefile, filesystems, strace

I have a CMake project I am working on, and when I run `"make"` then the rebuild of one of the targets is getting triggered regardless of whether I touch any of the files in the system. I have managed to discover that this is because one of the files on which the target depends is somehow getting deleted when I run `"make"`, so the system registers that it needs to be rebuilt. I tried setting `"chattr +i"` on this file to make it immutable and indeed, with this flag set, the rebuilding of the target is not triggered, though there are also no errors from a deletion attempt. But I think I can be sure that this is the culprit.

So now my question. How can I figure out what script or makefile is actually deleting this file? It is a big project with quite a few scripts and sub-makefiles which potentially run at different times during the build, so I am having a hard time manually discovering what is doing this. Is there some nice trick I can pull from the filesystem side to help? I tried doing `"strace make"`, but parsing the output I can't seem to find the filename appearing anywhere. I am no `strace` expert though, so perhaps the file is getting deleted via some identifier rather than the filename? Or I am not stracing spawned processes perhaps?

Comment: If the output doesn't include an actual call to `rm` (and you don't see it at the very end of the make output) then that makes things tougher. You can try running `make -d` (warning *lots* of output) to see if you can spot the filename being deleted in there or (possibly more helpfully) you can try `make SHELL+=-x` (or `make SHELLFLAGS+=-x` for make 4.0+) to get verbose output from the shell for the commands it runs.

Comment: Ahh, amazing, make -d helps a lot, nice to learn about that. From this output I can see that make is "Pruning" --which seems to be code for "deleting"-- the aforementioned file, because it thinks it is old or something. Never knew make did that. Anyway hopefully this helps me track down why it is doing that, thanks!

Comment: No, that's not what `Pruning` means. That's an internal prune for processing. It means make has already seen and considered the file. Keep loooking. The `SHELL`/`SHELLFLAGS` output is likely more useful here if something is actually calling `rm` on the file. I would also strongly suggest checking the *last* bit of output from make as make may be removing this file as an intermediate there (last from the output of a given call to `make` so recursive make might put that in the middle of the total output).

Comment: Also FYI, for makefiles generated by CMake you can pass the variable `VERBOSE=1` to see the commands that are being invoked by make (so, something like `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: Hmm ok not the "Pruning" then: The VERBOSE thing is helpful too, thanks: with a little grepping of that output I find "Deleting primary custom command output "<blah>" because another output "<blah>" does not exist." Seems like CMake programmed make to do this deletion on purpose. The plot thickens. I guess I need to track down why the other output of the custom command is missing...

Comment: another program to look at when debugging make is `remake`.

Comment: This isn't a make problem.  It's a cmake problem.  So, `remake` probably won't really help.  Also you should modify the tags for the question to be sure that cmake is there.

Comment: Try `strace -f -e process,unlink,unlinkat make`